# Can't See Asset in Case Standard Report

Tags: reporting

I built a report for one of my stakeholders using a standard case report type so he could use the Age field to count case times. He needs to see the Asset field on case on the report. However, it doesn't show up for either of us and I'm set as a system admin. I can see the field on the layout I can update it, but it doesn't show up on the report.

I tried googling and searching around and similar questions always seem to end up with are you sure you have access to the field? Which I do.

Some more details, it is hidden on some page layouts but visible on others. It's been renamed to 'Equipment' so it's not Asset when you view in the UI but it's not technically Equipment either as it's the standard object.

Comment: Even though you're a System Admin, it's good to double-check the Field-Level Security (FLS) for the Asset field. Go to Setup → Object Manager → Case → Fields & Relationships → Asset (or 'Equipment') and verify that the field is visible not only to your profile but more importantly the profile of the stakeholder.

Comment: Being able to view an Asset requires that you have View access on the Asset's Account and/or Contact record

Comment: Interesting, I have view/edit to those fields but we're not populating them on the Asset record by design.